# Separate image name from image path

Tags: django, python-2.7

**views.py**

```
def index(request):  
     profile = profiles.objects.all()
     for person in persons: 
         images = profile.image
         image = 'uploads/no-img.jpg'
         if images:
             [x.strip() for x in images.split('/')]
             image = images[-1:]
         p = image_name(image = image,activated = 1)
         p.save()
```

**models.py**

```
class profiles(models.Model):
     image = models.ImageField(blank=True,upload_to='%Y/%m/%d')
     user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

`2012/09/08/4f31063d985c97b64e930917b456083c.jpg` I want to separate the image name from this link.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename

Comment: 'ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute 'rfind
I got this error when i did this.**image =os.path.basename(images)**.

Comment: The argument to `basename` must be a string.

Comment: Now i convert my images to string 'str(image)' and got the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.path.basename(path)` : Returns the base name of pathname path passed as string.

```
>> os.path.basename('2012/09/08/4f31063d985c97b64e930917b456083c.jpg')
   4f31063d985c97b64e930917b456083c.jpg
```

Read more about it [here.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename)

Comment: Now i convert my images to string 'str(image)' and got the result.